# Can't write to txt files

Tags: c#, file

I am working on a program that reads certain .txt file with names and then writes in new data that you write.

In file there are names in every line:
First Name Last Name

When I add a customer and close the program I can see it in customers.txt file, but when I do it again it overwrites the existing added customer instead of making a new one under it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace CustomersList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string customers = File.ReadAllText("customers.txt");
            char inp = ' ';

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pick option!\r\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Add (A)\r\nEnd (E)");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Your option: ");
                Console.Write("");

                inp = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

                switch (inp)
                {

                    case 'A':
                        {

                            Console.Write("First Name: ");
                            string fName = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Write("Last Name: ");
                            string lName = Console.ReadLine();

                            StreamWriter write = File.CreateText("customers.txt");

                            write.WriteLine(customers);
                            write.Close();
                            AddN(fName, lName);
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            break;
                        }
                }
            } while (inp != 'E');


            Console.ReadKey();


        }

       static void AddN(string nameF, string nameL)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("customers.txt", nameF + " " + nameL.ToString());

    }


}
}
```

Any recomendations about what to change in that code? I would appreciate it!

Comment: File.WriteAllText(path, text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [`File.CreateText` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll notice this in the Remarks section:

> This method is equivalent to the StreamWriter(String, Boolean)
>   constructor overload with the append parameter set to **false**. If the
>   file specified by path does not exist, it is created. **If the file does
>   exist, its contents are overwritten.** Additional threads are permitted
>   to read the file while it is open.

What you want is [`File.AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates a StreamWriter that **appends** UTF-8 encoded text to an existing
>   file, or to a new file if the specified file does not exist.

```
StreamWriter write = File.AppendText("customers.txt");
write.WriteLine(customers);
write.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the line `StreamWriter write = File.CreateText("customers.txt");` you are re-creating the file every iteration of the loop. I'd sugest you to move the creation of the file outside the loop.

And of course only create the file only if you need/want to do it.